# Why does tcc not recognize "main" when I include the -pthreads flag?

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads, gtk, tcc

I am trying to compile a c application with the gtk 3.0 library with tcc. The documentation says the command to run to compile is

`` gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o [executable name] [source file] `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` ``

I am trying to use tcc to compile, and it from what I can tell, the syntax should be the same. However, where gcc compiles it fine, when I use tcc, compilation fails with the error:

`tcc: error: undefined symbol 'main'`

I isolated the problem to the -pthread flag inserted by `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` Thus, running a simple "Hello, World" c program and compiling with

`tcc -pthread -o [executable name] [source file]`

results in the same error. Am I compiling wrong, is it a compiler bug, or something else?

Comment: Look in the TCC documentation to see what `-pthread` means for your main program.

Comment: There were some recent issues with `-pthread` in TCC. See http://repo.or.cz/tinycc.git/commit/3b27b3b1d1ae953f5ecb37f5bc95758499d66971 and the two previous commits.

Answer (score 0):

try `-lpthread`

```sh
tcc hello.c -lpthread -o hello
```